# how to do a java swing server using sockets with a kotlin client?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, swing, sockets

first, it's even possible?
I'm trying to do an android app using kotlin that sends info, text, etc. to a java swing application using sockets. it's a class assignment so I can't change the technologies. Here's what I got so far but doesn't work, the client (kotlin) it's not sending the text. please help.

java server:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocketServer {
    private static final int PORT = 8080;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            System.out.println("Server started on port " + PORT);

            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                String message = input.readLine();
                System.out.println("Message received: " + message);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

kotlin client:

````
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.net.Socket




class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        main()
    }

    fun main() {
        val message = "Hola desde Kotlin!"
        val socket = Socket("localhost", 8080)
        val output = PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true)
        output.println(message)
        socket.close()
    }


}```
````

Comment: Do you run the Java server on PC and the Kotlin client in the Android device? If so, why do you connect to `localhost`?

Comment: no. I run both the java server and the android studio on my pc

Comment: ??? And where is your Android client app running?

Comment: `how to do a java swing server` AND `java server:`. We conclude that you have two servers. Why two? And where are they running?

Comment: `the client (kotlin) it's not sending the text. ` Before beeing able to send anything there should be a connection. You are not telling is a connection is established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're executing the Kotlin code on an android emulator. The Problem is that the localhost from your emulator is not the localhost from your PC.

You should try 10.0.2.2 according to the official android studio documentation:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking .